# drake visualizer not showing kuka iiwa simulation

Tags: drake

I tried to run the kuka simulation in drake from  both source and the binary release but it fails.

The error message is :

```
ERROR: In /vtk/IO/Import/vtkOBJImporter.cxx, line 495
vtkOBJPolyDataProcessor (0x55bb85982d30): Error reading 'v' at line 3
```

I checked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68952327/error-in-vtk-io-import-vtkobjimporter-cxx) but my libvtkIOGeometry is found in the drake library when I strace the command.

When running from binary , a warning shows :

```
[console] [warning] The use of kuka_simulation outside of Drake (i.e., via 'make install'  or a pre-compiled release image) is deprecated and will be removed from the install on or after 2022-01-01
```

Is it a problem in my installation or is there a problem in this example ? I have Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, bazel 4.2.1, gcc 7.5.0, python 3.6.9 and last stable drake release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance that your workstation or shell terminal is set to use a non-ASCII locale, where a period `.` is not the decimal fraction separator?

Comment: I do'nt think so. I siply used bash and amde no change to the locales

Comment: Hmm, ok.  To be sure, you could try `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` and then `LC_ALL=C ./kuka_simulation` or `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ./kuka_simulation`.

Comment: It was effectively a problem in LC_NUMERIC differences between fr_FR and en_US